# Can a static height be set for subreports in reporting services VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, service, reporting-services, reporting, subreport

I've made a report using reporting services (Visual Studio 2010) and I want the subreport to have a predefined height. For example, the subreport will be 2 in. even if the report data only fills up 1 in. of the subreport. Is there a way to force a subreport to have a static height?

Answer (score 3):

I have run into this same issue.

To set a minimum size, add a rectangle with a horizontal and vertical line inside it, and place the subreport inside the rectangle.

One solution I can think of for setting the max size, is to use top(x) in the sub report query, so that any results which exceed the number of lines to be shown are simply not included.

Alternatively, if all results must be included, then add a calculated field to the subreport dataset which counts the rows of data. In the subreport table, for each column set the font size such that all lines of data can be displayed within the given area. (iif(NoOfResults = 2, font = 10, etc))The 'Allow row height to decrease' will also need to be set on the table, so the rows can shrink in accord with the font size.

Hope someone finds this helpful. If you can think of any other solutions, I'd love to hear them.